# WordPress Custom php files stopped working in wp-admin folder

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I have some custom php files in the wp-admin folder, for example a bannereditor.php or an eventeditor.php, etc. You can edit some additional parameters for the posts with them. They have worked fine for two years, but now if I click on them they don’t open anymore, instead the home page of my webpage shows up. I made no modifications in my webpage for a while, and no matter what the content is in those php files, they simply don’t work anymore. I deactivated all plugins, but that did not help. My colleagues can’t set a banner for new posts anymore, and they can’t specify parameters for posts, e.g. location, date of event. What could be the reason for something stopped working that uesd to work before?

Comment: Putting files directly into wp-admin (or wp-includes) is probably not a good idea and is asking for trouble, but I'll leave that alone. Make sure that PHP error reporting is turned completely on. Do your custom PHP boot up a copy of WordPress manually? If so, make sure WP_DEBUG is set to true, too.

Comment: Even if I make a copy of any existing php file, for example "profile.php" and rename it to something else, the new file does not open anymore, wherease this method of making copies and renaming them to something else used to work earlier.

Comment: I would start by watching your access logs on the server (Apache, Nginx, etc.) to see if your script is actually being hit. I would also change your script to just `<?php die('here');` so that you have the simplest script to debug. If you don't see your script in the access logs, all rules from .htaccess (Apache) or simplify your location directives (Nginx) so that no one is getting in the way.